# The sign pi doesn't appear

Tags: math-mode

I'm writting a simple math book but I have a problem with the pi sign. I'm using a font which doesn't have the sign so it appears like this:

[image: Pi problem]

This is how I wrote it:

```
\textbf{Perímetro:} $2\pi r$\\
\textbf{Área:} $r\pi^2$\\+
```

And this is how I applied the font:

```
\newfontfamily{\miletra}{MILETRA}[
  NFSSFamily=MiLetra,
  Path=./,
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=3},
]

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{MiLetra}

\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{TU}{MiLetra}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{operators}

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{letters}
```

How can I make LaTeX use the pi sign from its math font without changing my font?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just noticed the ^2 should be on r, I will fix that too haha

Comment: obviously `\pi` normally works so the problem is with code you have not shown,. Please fix your question to have an example that produces the output shown.

Comment: I just edited it, thanks

Comment: oh you are using unicode tex you had not even mentioned that!

Comment: Welcome. // @ian, your >pruned< code should start with \documentclass, and at \end{document} and contain your code posted so far AND anything else which we need for a copy & compile run. The way you have simply doesn't. Thanks. (See David's last comment, and you know why ...)

Comment: You still have not shown any code that would produce the output shown. The declaration you added just defines a text font and would not affect math mode

Comment: Now it's enough? I'm not exactly sure what should I put, because puting the whole code I think would be too much. Thanks

Comment: you should provide an example but at least you have included a line of code that could be used to construct an example (`\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}`)

Comment: @ian, just prepare a document with the two lines that fails, adding the preamble needed to show the error. You can also read what a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is.

Comment: @ian, many newcomers have similar trouble with preparing MWEs like you may have. Kindly have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671760/how-to-reduce-prune-my-code-so-it-becomes-a-mwe-minimal-working-example/671761#671761 . Please don't feel bad about it: it's intended to help you and others along.

Answer (score 7):

A more reasonable example would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\miletra}{Comic Sans MS}[
  NFSSFamily=MiLetra,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=3},
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Perímetro:} $2\pi r$

\textbf{Área:} $\pi r^2$
\end{document}
```

(I picked a well known font without Greek)

You can define a symbol font using classic tex math encoding and redefine `\pi` to use that (copied from `fontmath.ltx` just changing `letters` to `grletters`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\miletra}{Comic Sans MS}[
  NFSSFamily=MiLetra,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=3},
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{grletters}{OML}{cmm} {m}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{grletters}{"19}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Perímetro:} $2\pi r$

\textbf{Área:} $\pi r^2$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can use `\newfontfamily`, you can use `unicode-math`, with something like:

```
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Miletra}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{Fira Math} % Or your math font of choice
\setmathfont{Miletra}[range=up/{Latin,latin,digits}]
```

While I don’t have your font to test, this will fall back to the Fira Math font for all symbols other than Latin letters and digits.

Comment: yes, I wondered if I should have suggested a unicode math answer.+1 here OP has a choice of fonts now:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your answer was very good! As is often the case, there was more than one way to do it, so I thought I’d post an alternative.