# The commas appear as semicolons in my document

Tags: math-mode

I'm writting a simple document with a font I created and I don't know why when I use mathmode the commas appear as semicolons and the points as double points.

Here's an example:

[image: Example]

This is the document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs,latexsym,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\miletra}{MiLetra}[
  NFSSFamily=MiLetra,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=3},
]

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{MiLetra}

\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{TU}{MiLetra}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\DeclareSymbolFont{grletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{grletters}{"19}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{operators}

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{letters}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

$(0,0)$

\end{document}
```

If someone knows what could I do in order to correct it I would be really thankful.

Comment: Interesting layout. Your question will be better if you add a complete but minimal example.

Comment: @mickep I am agree with you. But what is the MWE?

Comment: this is identical to your last question but with comma not pi and you still have provided no example

Comment: @Sebastiano A simple short compilable document, including the problematic character (a comma).

Comment: you based this on my answer, which requires remapping for all characters, I just  showd `\pi` there, you would be better to use the other `unicode-math` answer which replaces all the math code you show and will make , map correctly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The sign pi doesn't appear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671754/the-sign-pi-doesnt-appear)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the `unicode-math` answer to your previous question, but if you go this rout you need to declare characters for the TU (Unicode) font you are using (I again switched fonts to one I had available)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs,latexsym,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}



\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\miletra}{Comic Sans MS}[
  NFSSFamily=MiLetra,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=3},
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{MiLetra}

\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{TU}{MiLetra}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\DeclareSymbolFont{grletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{grletters}{"19}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{operators}

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{letters}

\DeclareMathSymbol{,}\mathpunct{numbers}{`,}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

$(0,0)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but I did the same for the point and it's not working

Comment: `\DeclareMathSymbol{.}\mathalpha{numbers}{\`.}` would work but spanish babel is mapping it back to comma, see if it has an option not to do that.  Failing that put `\mathcode\`\.=\`\.` _after_ `\begin{document}`